# Leer codigo QR con lector de QR externo

Tags: android, qr

Tengo un app de android para leer código QR. Funciona bien pero quiero utilizar un lector  (No cámara, lector. Se conecta por Usb al dispositivo) de QR. en vez de la cámara del dispositivo android.

Cuando pulso el boton scanear hace esto:

```
   public void onClick(View view) {
           IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);

//integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);

integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
        integrator.setPrompt("Scaner");
        integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
        integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
        integrator.initiateScan();
        }
```

y luego recojo la respuesta en `onActivityResult(...)`

Apunto con el lector y detecta el codigo pero no me muestra nada, con la camara del dispositivo si funciona correctamente.

Un saludo.

Comment: Bienvenido ..., te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, ¿Que tipo de lector usas?, debes agregar más información!

Comment: los lectores externos tengo entendido que funcionan como dispositivo de entrada de texto (como un teclado) al menos así son reconocidos por las PC para el celular debería ser lo mismo siempre que reconozca el dispositivo

Comment: El dispositivo si funciona. me descargue una app de play store para verificar el funcionamiento y si va bien. En mi aplicacion, cuando lee un qr emite un pitido pero no obetengo la respuesta como si lo enfocara con la camara del propio móvil o tablet. Gracias por vuestras respuestas.